# Playwright TypeError: 'function' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python, pyrogram

I use Pyrogram to troll messages from the Telegram channel. Next, I extract the necessary data, which I use Playwright to enter into a form on some site.

Here is an example of the code:

```py
import re
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from typing import AsyncGenerator


from pyrogram import filters, Client
from pyrogram.types import Message
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


from keys import API_ID, API_HASH, CANAL_ID_IMEX, LOGIN, PASSWORD, URL


client = Client("my_session", api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)


async def get_codes(message: Message) -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    """Example of the message text:
    'ZM_GDB4SRHQNK Activate in bonuses.'
    """
    promo = [c
             for codes in re.findall(
                 r"(^[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{10})",
                 message.text, flags=re.MULTILINE
                 )
             for c in codes if c]

    for code in promo:
        yield code


@client.on_message(filters.chat(CANAL_ID_IMEX))
async def message_handler(client: Client, message: Message) -> None:
    async for code in get_codes(message):
        with async_playwright() as playwright:
            browser = await playwright.chromium.launch()
            context = await browser.new_context()
            page = await context.new_page()
            await page.goto(URL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run()
```

This line `with async_playwright() as playwright:` leads to the following error:

```
2024-03-08 21:16:02,915 - INFO - 256 | 2024-03-08 21:16:03 | ZM_Z263A89F4R | 0:00:00.000022 
2024-03-08 21:16:02,915 - ERROR - 'function' object does not support the context manager protocol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/svbazuev/Zooma/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "/home/svbazuev/Zooma/main.py", line 99, in message_handler
    with async_playwright() as playwright:
TypeError: 'function' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

When I made the changes suggested by [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen):

```py
@client.on_message(filters.chat(CANAL_ID_IMEX))
async def message_handler(client: Client, message: Message) -> None:
    async for code in get_codes(message):
        if code:
            async with async_playwright as p:
                browser = await p.chromium.launch()
```

I got this error:

```
2024-03-09 13:02:59,842 - INFO - 274 | 2024-03-09 13:02:59 | ZM_726HBNYRA2 | 0:00:00.000029 
2024-03-09 13:02:59,843 - ERROR - 'function' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/svbazuev/Zooma/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "/home/svbazuev/Zooma/main.py", line 100, in message_handler
    async with async_playwright as p:
TypeError: 'function' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
```

If I first save the necessary data and upload it separately to the form, I succeed. But I want to execute immediately without saving intermediate results.

I didn't find any explicit instructions in the documentation. I must be missing something. How to solve it?

At first, I used the synchronous implementation of Playwright (Windows OS). I think the problem is related to this. The asynchronous version of Playwright (OS Linux) is already being used in the code example. But I could be wrong...

## Resume

## Thanks to [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen)'s attentiveness, it became clear that there was no problem.

***I was inattentive myself and missed `async` in this line:***
`with async_playwright() as playwright:`
***And then, looking into [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen)'s "notebook", I missed `()` in this line:***
`async with async_playwright as p:`

### Be careful!

Comment: The docs [suggest](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/library#usage) `async with async_playwright() as p:`. Did you try that?

Comment: [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen), I added the result to the text of the question, thank you.
Now it has become clear that it is not a matter of synchronous or asynchronous execution.  
The problem is in the content manager protocol, but what's the catch here?!  

Let's try all the wrong solutions, sooner or later we'll find the right one!
**Let's go!**

Comment: You're missing the parentheses: `async with async_playwright as p:` rather than `async with async_playwright() as p:`. Please copy my code exactly as it is above. See also [How to solve TypeError: 'type' object does not support context manager protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273001/how-to-solve-typeerror-type-object-does-not-support-context-manager-protocol)

Comment: You're right, I knew I was looking in the wrong direction...
it turned out that it wasn't a problem, but just nonsense. 
Thanks for showing me.
Good luck!